# Redux-saga mocking apis for development purpose

Tags: javascript, redux, mocking, redux-saga

I'm using "redux-saga": "^1.0.2"

I wanted to mock my APIs using redux-saga and didn't find proper answers online.

I finally ended up with a very basic but easy solution: using Promise.

Could you give me some feedback about this technique? Would you have some better recommendations?

```
import { takeEvery, call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";

let mock = 1

function getdata() {
  if (mock === 0) {
    return fetch("https://your_own_address").then(response =>
      response.json()
    );
  }
  else {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve({data: {id: 1}})
    })
  }
}

export default function* watcherSaga() {
  yield takeEvery("GET_DATA", workerSagaGetData);
}

function* workerSagaGetData() {
  try {
    const payload = yield call(getdata);
    yield put({ type: "DATA_SUCCESS", payload });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({ type: "DATA_ERROR", payload: e });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `fetch`, i.e. with [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) npm package (it's the first one google suggested, perhaps there are other solutions too).

You also can add some env variable to track if mock is needed i.e. somewhere in your `mock.js`:

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_MOCK_FETCH) {
    fetchMock.mock(
       'https://your_own_address',
       JSON.stringify({data: {id: 1}})
     );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll check this out and will let you know. Thanks